# How to read a variable in the robot framework with a "#" in front of it

Tags: string, random, escaping, robotframework

I am trying to create a random color generation in the robot framework. This is my code:

'''
Random Color
${color_hex}=     Generate Random String     6     [NUMBERS]ABCDEF
${color_rand}=     Catenate     SEPARATOR=     #     ${color_hex}
'''

When I try to use ${color_rand} as an argument it does not work. The framework reads it as a comment instead of a string. I specifically need a "#" before 6 hex values for my color picker to work. If I use a backslash() to escape and make it a string (i.e. ${color_rand}) it reads the value, "${color_rand}" vs what I want which is, "#123CDE". I don't know what to do for the framework to read the string, WITH the #, and not have it be a comment.

Comment: Please show a proper [mcve]. Your example is not valid robotframework code.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really use a [backslash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash).

If you do use it, you get a string with a `#`, an example in RF:

```
*** Variables ***
${hex}=    \#fcba03
```

Comment: For some reason, I cannot properly edit my code so that it looks how it should. If you try to edit my initial question you should be able to view what I am trying to convey.

Comment: I read through your question again and I think I did understand it correctly and my answer is a solution to your problem. Could you either confirm it, or say what does't work?